# Elegant way to get a value out Boto3 response dict

Tags: python, boto, boto3

I'm using `boto3` to describe my pipelines to me. It throws back a response in a very curious format -

```
{'ResponseMetadata': {'HTTPStatusCode': 200,
                      'RequestId': '2c42a320-c6ab-11e5-a021-afa8e3e7ca24'},
 u'pipelineDescriptionList': [{u'fields': [{u'key': u'key1', u'stringValue': u'AIDAIxxxxxxNWNI6I'},
                                           {u'key': u'key2', u'stringValue': u'2016-01-29T13:32:09'},
                                           {u'key': u'key3', u'stringValue': u'ABCD'},
                                           {u'key': u'key4', u'stringValue': u'PIPELINE'}],
                               u'name': u'ABCD',
                               u'pipelineId': u'df-03442XXXXAZTRKE4NNK',
                               u'tags': []},
                              {u'fields': [{u'key': u'key1',u'stringValue': u'2016-01-29T11:26:02'},
                                           {u'key': u'key2', u'stringValue': u'[{"key":"jobrun","value":"RzIN"},{"key":"env","value":"prod"}]'},
                                           {u'key': u'key3', u'stringValue': u'2016-01-29T11:25:20'},
                                           {u'key': u'key4', u'stringValue': u'PIPELINE'}],
                               u'name': u'test-pipeline',
                               u'pipelineId': u'df-006474936ZXRQ238Q70O',
                               u'tags': [{u'key': u'jobrun', u'value': u'RWssN'},{u'key': u'env', u'value': u'prod'}]}]}
```

Now I'm interested in getting pipeline 'ABCD's `key2` value. If I try to get it in the most intuitive way, it gets very messy since I'll have to iterate through each of the `pipelineDescriptionList` list items, iterate through each of the list items in 'fields', check the one for which `key` equals `key2`, and get the `stringValue` for that.

My question is, are we actually expected to deal with this mess? Or is there some Python magic that can make my task more elegant?

Answer (score 8):

One option would be to use [jmespath](http://jmespath.org/) which is bundled with boto3.  It's a pretty powerful tool for processing JSON-like data structures.

For example, if the response you show above was bound to the variable `response` you could do this:

```
jmespath.search("pipelineDescriptionList[?name == 'ABCD'].fields[] | [?key == 'key2'].stringValue", response)
```

which would return:

```
[u'2016-01-29T13:32:09']
```

There may be better ways to do it, that's just a quick cut at it.  You can also *compile* these expressions to make things a bit more efficient for doing many searches with the same query.